# How did hackers gain access to my Chrome and my social media accounts?

Tags: windows, chrome, twitter, instagram

These are the things that have happened to me in the last few hours:

Weird tweets such as "Hello 91" and "Hello 87" were being tweeted from my account.

My Instagram account had weird activity, as in a few minutes I was following almost 1000 people.

I had no idea how this had happened because I didn't receive any kind of "access from new device" type of email from either of my two accounts (2FA was off, huge mistake, by the way).

I tried to log in to my Gmail account from my laptop which didn't work and i received a suspicious activity warning and was asked to run a security check on my own. Which i did, using windows defender and another paid security application. Both of them showed nothing.

I uninstalled every browser extension, changed my password, and uninstalled every extra app from my computer.

Then I took a look at the task manager and found something suspicious. There were multiple Google Chrome processes running, even though I don't even use Chrome (I am an Edge user).

So I decided to uninstall Chrome, but it wouldn't allow me, claiming that I should first close all windows. Even though nothing was shown in the task bar.

There was something fishy, so I opened Chrome and checked my browsing history, which was filled with various Instagram and Twitter visits from a few minutes ago. Someone had access to my browser.

I cut off my internet and turned off the computer.

I want to know how I was hacked, how the Chrome window was not visible at all while the hacker was able to use it, and also why they were sending weird tweets. Also, what should I do now?

Comment: Looks like malware is running locally on your PC. If that's the case, backup everything, reinstall from scratch after wiping your disk clean. How did it happen, I've no idea.

Comment: "But suddenly I got a message from Google (on my browser) saying that my computer had malware and I should run a security check. I did and it showed nothing." This sounds like a fake message enticing you to click something and accept a security prompt. That could be the ingress point right there. You should always launch your security software yourself, directly, from your taskbar or start menu. Did you?

Comment: "I want to know how I was hacked" this requires an investigation in order to be answered. Your description is not detailed enough for this to happen. I would suggest that you reinstalled your OS and start from scratch - trying to locate and selectively remove malware from your computer is like looking for a needle in a haystack and odds are that you'll miss something and the said malware will keep creating problems

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, I did wipe my drive clean, and reinstalled my OS. Everything is fine now. Still won't understand the weird tweets the hacker sent, probably they were automated but served what purpose?

Comment: @JohnWu hi, That message was genuine in my opinion. I was trying to access Gmail, through the official website.  the message warned me of suspicious activity originating from my device and prevented me to log in(which probably also stopped the hacker) . I also got an email and security popup on my phone asking me to immediately change the password due to suspicious activity from my computer. Yes, I did use my own security software for scanning from my taskbar (which was windows defender and another paid cyber security application). Both of them showed nothing.

Comment: @Spyros thanks i did reinstall my OS. But what i fail to understand is what kind of hacker , uses hidden Chrome windows , to browse and access my social media only to post some cryptic tweets and follow a group of people on Instagram. Did he had access to my computer? Or only my browser? Which i don't even use. And how did he manage to hide it.

Comment: it's very difficult to answer all of these questions without actually conducting an investigation on the incident. As for the tweets, I can only guess; you may have been infected by a worm of some kind and tweeting specially crafted messages may be the way to signal the attacker that an infection took place. But everything is just speculation at this point so take everything with a grain of salt when it comes to the whys and hows

Comment: Seeing as how the popup seems *not* malicious, and the activity was in Chrome, the only thing that makes sense to me is that someone somehow managed to remotely activate Chrome - maybe by sending you some specific download that would have run Chrome (I know some Google Drive MIME types can fire up Chrome). **Even so, it seems to me that some consent on your end would have been required**. From there, and without 2FA, the attacker might have been able to get your GMail saved credentials, and with that they would have been able to recover access to any number of social accounts such as Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

This is, you understand, an hypothesis - without thoroughly examining your PC, finding the malware, and reverse engineering it, there's no way to be sure.

Let us assume that a breach in Chrome took place **somehow** (possibly by having Edge download a malicious package that would have been passed to Chrome due to specific MIME type and/or extension).

At this point the attacker has limited control of the Chrome browser, and can't simply access the rest of your machine without running afoul of privilege requests, confirmation dialogs and all sort of other alarms.

What they *can* do is probably access credentials stored in the browser (unless protected by a master password), and run code in a isolated browser thread. This latter happens all the time for legitimate purposes (usually to have "push alerts" sent to your PC).

That thread might have refused any requests to terminate (normal threads would exit gracefully), which prevents closing and uninstalling the browser, and this would explain the problems you encountered there.

This capability of the browser to run a hidden background task is **a feature** and is used for lots of legitimate purposes - the attacker is abusing a feature, but needn't have fearsome knowledge or capabilities to be able to *create* that feature. It was already there.

Being able to do the same things you can do *in a browser*, this kind of agent **usually** sends clicks or traffic, raising revenue from advertisements, or "likes" and "follows", or can create fake accounts that are re-sold to boost numbers for marketing purposes. Or (and) it can run several kinds of crypto-miners. This then would explain you abruptly following lots of people. Those people bought followers (to boast having one million followers), but those followers aren't real - they come from abused machines like yours.

I've also heard people found themselves having bought and "gifted" all sorts of easily resalable items to unknown people across the world. Having access to your Amazon account is enough to do that (and the reason why Amazon won't let you change your destination delivery address without requiring further confirmation).

If running on your same browser, the code can also intercept what you enter into websites (such as banking sites, or e-shops).

But even if it runs on Chrome and you use Edge, Chrome might have access to your webmail, which could then be examined looking for financial information and/or material for identity thefts, and/or supplying information to more surely involve you in follow-up scams. As a simplistic example, if they know you *do* have an Aunt Ann, you might be more likely to respond when "Aunt Ann" emails you asking for a small loan, maybe even quoting unrelated earlier information ("I hope your exam went well" or such).

That this is a definite possibility is indicated by those tweets like "Hello 91". That's a common way of signaling a successful infection to a command-and-control network. The malware running inside the browser will listen for replies (or read unrelated tweets from a different, overlooked account half the Internet away nobody would think of checking):

```
 Victim: "Tweet 10. Tweet 91. Tweet 45"
 mariorossi@antarctica: "10-91-45 john doe 47"
 johndoe47@backendofnowhere: "Scan Google account"
```

The malware only has to send its identification code, and read a single known account (or web page) to acquire the address of its new control account (or web page, chat room, facebook friend). Human crackers using the control account now can manage your machine by sending tweets on the new account (and this is only *one* way of doing this kind of things). The traffic looks like legitimate social networking, and thus bypasses all kinds of checks and firewalls.

Comment: This is a very long hypothesis, not an answer. Without proper forensics it's impossible to say what actually happened.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You're right; I tried to answer the points on "how the Chrome window was not visible at all [...] and also why they were sending weird tweets" in context. But I have included your comment at the beginning.

Comment: @LSerni Hi, and thankyou for the detailed response. I would like to clarify few things not mentioned in the original question. So yes you guessed it right, I actually received a suspicious activity warning and was asked to run a security check on my own. Which i did, using windows defender and another paid security application. Both of them showed nothing. I don't think i have ever clicked those fishy popups, regardless I use edge but the fact that my chrome browser (not opened for months) was compromised is also suspicious. Don't think that browser threads can switch applications... (1)

Comment: Even if the hacker gained access using another pathway (let's say not through the browser) , how was he able to keep my chrome window hidden. Your explanation for those weird tweets is probably very accurate. Thankyou  (2)